# C# get value from deserialized json object

Tags: c#, json

I'm currently Deserializing a json string using the Newtonsoft.Json nuget packet using the following code:

```
var data = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```

Now I'm receiving an object in the following format:

```
{{  "meta": {    "rap": 2098,    "count": 5  },  "data": [    {      "name": "Gold Tetramino of Mastery",      "rap": 735,      "uaid": "16601901",      "link": "https://www.roblox.com/Gold-Tetramino-of-Mastery-item?id=5786047",      "img": "https://t4.rbxcdn.com/081337d7ea86e6a406512aaa83bbcdeb",      "serial": "---",      "count": 1    },    {      "name": "Silver Tetramino of Accomplishment",      "rap": 385,      "uaid": "16601900",      "link": "https://www.roblox.com/Silver-Tetramino-of-Accomplishment-item?id=5786026",      "img": "https://t1.rbxcdn.com/60da69cd76f8dad979326f63f4a5b657",      "serial": "---",      "count": 1    },    {      "name": "Subzero Ski Specs",      "rap": 370,      "uaid": "155175547",      "link": "https://www.roblox.com/Subzero-Ski-Specs-item?id=19644587",      "img": "https://t4.rbxcdn.com/8ead2b0418ef418c7650d34103d39b6d",      "serial": "---",      "count": 1    },    {      "name": "Rusty Tetramino of Competence",      "rap": 319,      "uaid": "16601899",      "link": "https://www.roblox.com/Rusty-Tetramino-of-Competence-item?id=5785985",      "img": "https://t2.rbxcdn.com/968ad11ee2f4ee0861ae511c419148c8",      "serial": "---",      "count": 1    },    {      "name": "Bluesteel Egg of Genius",      "rap": 289,      "uaid": "16601902",      "link": "https://www.roblox.com/Bluesteel-Egg-of-Genius-item?id=1533893",      "img": "https://t7.rbxcdn.com/48bf59fe531dd1ff155e455367e52e73",      "serial": "---",      "count": 1    }  ]}}
```

Now I'm trying to get the following value from it:

```
"rap": 2098,
```

**I just need 2098** and I've been trying the following code:

```
string rap = data["rap"].Value<string>();
```

But sadly this wouldn't work. Does anyone have a idea how to get the value?

Comment: Parse it instead of deserializing if you only need one value

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
var result = data["meta"]["rap"].Value<int>();
```

or

```
var result = data.SelectToken("meta.rap").ToString();
```

or if you don't want to want to pass the whole path in, you could just search for the property like this:

```
var result = data.Descendants()
                 .OfType<JProperty>()
                 .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "rap")
                 ?.Value;
```

Comment: I know this was posted a while ago, but this is just another great example from the stack community of knowledge sharing with the multiple different ways to help address this issue.  Thank you @stuart!

Answer (score 5):

Instead of declaring as type var and letting the compiler sort it, declare as a dynamic and using the Parse method.

```
dynamic data = JArray.Parse(json);
```

Then try

```
data.meta.rap
```

To get the internal rap object.
I edited from using the deserializeobject method as i incorrectly thought that had the dynamic return type. See here on json.net documentation for more details: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonDynamic.htm

Comment: There is no `Parse` method on `JsonConvert`.

Comment: As suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47134936/json-parsing-in-c-sharp-item-is-not-an-array, I'm using `dynamic data = JObject.Parse(json);`, which seems to work without exceptions.

Comment: in case anyone having a problem with this. it depends on how your Json is returned. try both JArray and Jobject.

Answer (score 5):

I just came to add *Yet another way to get 2098*:

---

After having got your object in the way you actually did:

```
var data = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```

The first you have to note is that the value you want to get is itself a value of the property `"meta"`:

[image: Exact location of the desired value inside the Json object]

so, first you have to extract the contents of `"meta"` by simply calling

```
data["meta"]
```

and just then you are able to ask for the `Value<string>` of `"rap"`:

```
String rap = data["meta"].Value<string>("rap");
```

which acctually gives you the value you were looking for:

```
Console.WriteLine(rap); // 2098
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var jobject = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
var jvalue = (JValue)jobject["meta"]["rap"];
Console.WriteLine(jvalue.Value); // 2098
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use as following

```
var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(param);

var testDTO = new TPRDTO();
testDTO.TPR_ID = test.TPR_ID.Value;
```

**Note:** For using of `JsonConvert` class you have to install **Newton-Soft** from your **package-manager**

Answer (score 1):

The value is actually an `int` type. Try:

```
int rap = data["rap"].Value<int>();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string rap = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json).meta.rap;
Console.WriteLine(rap); // 2098
```

If you're not into `dynamic` (or aren't using .NET 4+), I like how [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41753097/402749) relies solely on Json.NET's API.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you are casting the deserialized json into a JObject. if you want to have the JObject then simple do this:

```
JObject.Parse(json);
```

then you have the JObject and you can access a specific path (for extracting value see [this](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) )

you have also another option which is to deserialize your json into a class that you have in your code like this:

```
var instanceOFTheClass =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourClassName>(json);
```

with the above code you can access any property and values you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use the enumerator to get at the value:

```
var data = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
var enumerator = data.GetEnumerator();
enumerator.MoveNext();
var dataValue = enumerator.Current.Value.ToString();
```

Comment: Interesting approach @Rian, but sadly it gives the following result: 
{
  "rap": 2098,
  "count": 5
}

Answer (score 0):

Just use dynamic representation of object:

```
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json)
var value = obj.meta.rap;
```

JObject easily convertable to dynamic type itself. You can either get string or int from this value:

```
var ivalue = (int)obj.meta.rap;
var svalue = (string)obj.meta.rap;
```