# JSON parsing in c# item is not an array

Tags: c#, json, json.net, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to parse a JSON string, that looks like that:

```
{
    "totalCreditsRemoved": 1,
    "invalidReceivers": [],
    "ids": [100070531],
    "validReceivers": ["+33635938286"]
}
```

I retrieve this from a web API, and stock it as a String:

```
var reader = new StreamReader(respStream);
String result = reader.ReadToEnd().Trim();
response = result;
```

Response is a public string

Then, in another method: I try to parse my json string:

```
var json = response;
var objects = JArray.Parse(json);

foreach (JObject root in objects)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<String, JToken> app in root)
    {
        totalCreditsRemoved = (String)app.Value["totalCreditsRemoved"];
        invalidReceivers = (String)app.Value["invalidReceivers"];
        ids = (String)app.Value["ids"];
        validReceivers = (String)app.Value["validReceivers"];
    }
}
```

But I always get this error:

> JsonReaderException: Error reading JArray from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an array: StartObject. Path '', line 1, position 1.

The error occurs at this line:

```
var objects = JArray.Parse(json);
```

I don't understand how to fix this ? Isn't OVHjson already an array
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The response does not represent an array, so it can't be parsed by `JArray.Parse`.

Comment: Exactly what it says. From what you posted, the JSON is an object, not an array.

Comment: Use the *correct* method - if the content is an object use JObject.Parse. Better yet, create a DTO (ie a class with the properties you want) and deserialize the entire object at once, eg `var myDTO = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyDTO>(input); Console.WriteLine(myDTO.totalCredits);`

Comment: looks like your api method is not consistent in the response format (sometimes it returns array, sometimes it returns object). That's a very kind of bad design I've encountered with when working with some partners.

Comment: I effectively receive an object, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need for JArray.Parse as it is not a array ..and is doing an overkill..hence the error..

> var objects   = JObject.Parse(json);

will do the job

and to extract

```
totalCreditsRemoved = (String)objects.Value["totalCreditsRemoved"];
invalidReceivers = (String)objects.Value["invalidReceivers"];
ids = (String)objects.Value["ids"];
validReceivers = (String)objects.Value["validReceivers"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseFromServer);
 foreach (var obj in obj1.Properties())
 {
     if (obj.Name == "rewardConfirmation") {
         foreach (var obj2 in obj.Value)
         {
             MessageBox.Show(obj2.ToString());
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please consider to add some explanation for your answer by editing it.